# Avro - java.io.IOException: Not a data file

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, avro, avro-tools

I am using https://github.com/allegro/json-avro-converter to convert my json message into an avro file. After calling the convertToAvro method I get a byte array: byte[] byteArrayJson. Then I am using the commons library from Apache:

```
FileUtils.writeByteArrayToFile(myFile.avro, byteArrayJson);
```

The file is created. When I try to reconvert it to json, using:

```
java -jar avro-tools-1.8.1.jar tojson myFile.avro > testCheck.json


Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Not a data file.
    at 
org.apache.avro.file.DataFileStream.initialize(DataFileStream.java:105)
    at org.apache.avro.file.DataFileStream.<init>(DataFileStream.java:84)
    at org.apache.avro.tool.DataFileReadTool.run(DataFileReadTool.java:71)
    at org.apache.avro.tool.Main.run(Main.java:87)
    at org.apache.avro.tool.Main.main(Main.java:76)
```

I have created a Junit test and used convertToJson method (from the previous link) and assert the strings and it is everything ok. But with the jar it is not working. Am I doing something wrong? I am using the cmd, not powerShell, because I saw in a SO post that this can change the encoding. I think that the problem is with encoding, but I have no idea where to look. 
(I am using windows as OS)

Comment: I don't understand avro but check this out and tell me if you're following the same steps? https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/32034/avro-javaioioexception-javaioioexception-not-a-dat.html

Comment: you can also do like this https://avro.apache.org/docs/1.8.2/gettingstartedjava.html

Comment: I had a look at both this links before posting, I am using the library from github because is really easy to play with it. You can convertToJson or convertToAvro very easy, but the only think is I want to store the byte array into an avro file. And when I store it and try to convert it using avro-tools is not working. I think I have some wrong bytes, as it is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51148486/java-io-ioexception-not-a-data-file-after-converting-json-to-avro-with-avro-tool

Comment: The Windows 10 PowerShell transforms the binary stream into a UTF8 stream. Changing the encoding changes the magic bytes, which (correctly) causes the exception to be thrown.

Side note: the PowerShell app can be forced not to change the encoding by using a pipe instead of greater-than like so:

can you try like this from powershell

    java -jar .\avro-tools-1.7.7.jar fromjson --schema-file .\data.avsc .\data.json | .\data.avro

Comment: Yes, is the answer from the link I posted. But as I mentioned in the post, I am using cmd, so no changes should happen. But I think that when the file is created something is going wrong, but IDK what

Comment: @Agata may i ask why you are using code to write the file and tools JAR to read the JSON back ? why not code ?

Comment: Easier to visualize and test with different json.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that the avro file do not contain same data when produced from these 2 different ways and this is expected behavior.

As a test, use this command to generate the avro file

```
java -jar avro-tools-1.8.2.jar fromjson  --schema-file avroschema.json
testCheck.json > myFile2.auro
```

Now read this and print in Java, and notice that it doesnt contain ONLY AVRO RECORD
It contains the scme as well ( at least )  -see the String converted data below.
This means the data in AVRO files is different when generated using acro tools and when using avro converter

```
bjavro.schemaœ{"type":"record","name":"Acme","fields":[{"name":"username","type":"string"}]}avro.c
```

The validation within tools API "fails" when you try to read an avro file generated from converter with **tojson** command.

Now the correct command to use to read the "json" using avro tools when the file is generated using converter is **fragtojson**. See that we are really reading only JSON fragment ( an avro record here )

```
java -jar avro-tools-1.8.2.jar fragtojson --schema-file avroschema.json myFile.avro > myFile21.json
```

Another thought here is avoid using AVRO tools altogether and create your own executable jar with converter as dependency, and use it read AVRO JSON records.

Answer (score 0):

After I had a look at the avro files, I saw that the one created using avro-tools has the schema in it and the one created by the library from github doesn't. So I don't use the method from the library convertToAvro, but I am using convertToGenericDataRecord and then create my own dataFileWriter and set the record (which was obtained after calling the convertToGenericDataRecord method).